# paypal button / IPN invoice name

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My current set up for accepting payments goes like this:

1. I use custom paypal button codes, where I set up my notify url (IPN) and return url with parameters I want to pass (for example UTM_SOURCE so I can tell which campaign generated the sale).
2. I have a listener for the IPN that gets that information, and creates a new user in my system for the buyer.
3. I forward the IPN with a multiple IPN php script (http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/11/how-to-setup-multiple-ipn-receivers-in-paypal/) to a 3rd party invoicing software, which generates an invoice, and sends it to the buyer.

THE ISSUE:

The invoicing software gets the user's name from their paypal account, and it seems like a lot of people need the invoice to be on a different name.

Is there a way to manipulate the buyer's name, so that when I forward the IPN info to the invoicing software it will include the name that I have in my records rather than the name paypal passes?

NOTE: I'd rather do this without resorting to use the paypal's API.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP example of how you could accomplish that. Essentially, you loop through the IPN values and than add them back into your own string of name/value pairs. But before adding each value to your string, you check to see if its the first or last name, and if it is, you set it equal to some variable that you've already set.

```
$modified_first_name = "Bob";
$modified_last_name = "Smith";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {         // Loop through the notification NV pairs
    //Check if is first or last name, and modify the name
    switch ($key) {
        case 'first_name':
            $value = $modified_first_name;
            break;
        case 'last_name':
            $value = $modified_last_name;
            break;
    } //end switch $key

    //Add to NV pairs
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  // Encode these values
    $req  .= "&$key=$value";                   // Add the NV pairs to the acknowledgement
}
```

Edit: As for the second part of your question (sending the notification to the 3rd party software), you shouldn't send the IPN to the 3rd party software at all. Instead, using the data derived from the script I pasted above, send the data using POST to the 3rd party software yourself. You can do that like this:

```
// post to third party software //
$header .= "POST /script.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.thirdpartysoftwaresite.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$port = 123; //replace this with actual port on server

// Open a socket for the 3rd party software
$fp = fsockopen('http://www.thirdpartysoftwaresite.com/', $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// Send the HTTP POST request
fputs($fp, $header . $req);
```